# Permission denied to read file owned by www-data from script

Tags: command-line, permissions

I am trying to copy a file from a location and save it with another name using a Python script, but I am getting this error:

```
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/nginx-files/0000000007'
```

which is quite obvious that the script performing the operation has no permissions to do that.

Here are the user & group of the script:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data 1504 Jun  3 16:27 main.py
```

User & group of the file:

```
-rw-------  1 www-data www-data 40448 Jun  3 16:19 0000000007
```

User & group of the directory in which the file resides:

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data www-data  4096 Jun  3 16:56 nginx-files
```

These files are generated directly by `nginx`

I run my script from my own user account using

```
python main.py
```

How can I allow my script to read this file and prevent the permission error?

Comment: Which user runs the script? It must be `www-data`. Is it?

Comment: to run the script i use `python main.py`. how do i run it  with a particular user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the owner of the script that matters when deciding what it is allowed to do, but the user who executes the script.

In your question/comments, it seems like you run it with your own user account, not `www-data`, so the script can do exactly what you as user can do.

```
-rw-------  1 www-data www-data 40448 Jun  3 16:19 0000000007
```

This file is only readable and writable by its owner, `www-data`. A script running eon your user account can obviously not access it, hence the permission Error in your Python script.

---

So I see two ways how this could be resolved:

- Run the script as `www-data`. This can be done using `sudo`, if your account has admin rights. Otherwise some special configuration would be necessary to allow you running stuff as `www-data`. If you have `sudo` rights though, it becomes as simple as:

  ```
  sudo -u www-data python main.py
  ```
- Open up the permissions of the `0000000007` file so that it's readable and writable by its group too, not just the owner, but also still not everyone:

  ```
  sudo chmod g+rw 0000000007
  ```

  Now make sure your own user is also a member of the `www-data` group, so that it can profit from these group permissions:

  ```
  sudo adduser YOUR_USERNAME www-data
  ```

  You will have to log out and back in after this to allow the group changes of your user account to take effect.

  Now you should be able to access the file, and so will any script that you run under your account.